# Organizing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

Ok i've some issue to understand how to organize my controllers.

I will use a simple example: I want to create a car which needs colors, motors, wheels. 
I need different views per options.

What is the best method to organize controllers.

```
  class CarsController < ApplicationControler

     def select_wheels
        #some code
     end


     def select_colors
        #some code
     end


     def select_motors
        #some code
     end

     ##CRUD methods of Cars : index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy

  end
```

I'm searching for best practice.
Thank you And sorry for my poor english.

Aubin

Comment: Did I need to create different controllers for each option selection ?

Comment: Do you have Motor, Wheel as models? and do you have them associated with Car? then you should have separate controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create separate controllers for each attributes.
 See for each attributes we can make objects, so there is proper way to represent object oriented.
  So you have to initialize a class and make attributes as an object.
   And call class.object accordingly.

```
class Car
 attr_accessor :colors, :motors, :wheels
  def initialize(colors, motors, wheels)
   @colors = colors
   @motors = motors
   @wheels = wheels
  end  
end
```

Comment: I agree with that. But i need three views for the selection. So i want to know if i've to use three methods for the selection in my car controller.

Comment: No need to create three new methods. you can create normal CURD methods and call the particular objects.

Comment: I don't really understand. Did you have an example ? I want a `<select>` in each views to select the options.